# Bloomfire Bad Request

Tags: php, curl

I've been getting 400 Status Code(Bad Request) when I send a Post Request to Bloomfire User Creation.
../api/v2/users [This is endpoint]
The request body is-

```
{
'session_token':session_token,
"email": "john_smith@email.com",
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request body there is invalid json. Try:

```
{
    "session_token": "session_token",
    "email": "john_smith@email.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith"
}
```